# calculate bounding box after canvas.scale()

Tags: android, scale, bounds, bounding-box

my Android Applikation can draw multiple circles like this:
[image]

The User can also drag the circles and scale them. When it comes to scaling I used:

```
canvas.save();
   canvas.scale(this.scaleFactor, this.scaleFactor, this.centerX, this.centerY);
   // draw main circle
   canvas.drawCircle(this.centerX, this.centerY, this.radius, this.outerCirclePaint);
   ...
```

Everything is fine, except the bounding boxes of each text around the circle. Each text should be touchable (and it's not after canvas.scale). So I also tried to scale the bounding box with different methods and different results. 
When I just multiply the left,top,right,bottom of the box, the text is only touchable when the center of the circle is in 0,0. So I don't know why it is translated to 0,0.

```
txtBounds.set(txtBounds.left * this.scaleFactor, txtBounds.top * this.scaleFactor, txtBounds.right * this.scaleFactor, txtBounds.bottom * this.scaleFactor);
```

When I use a matrix to scale the box, the box seems to be alright but it isn't touchable any more

```
matrixBounds.setScale(this.scaleFactor, this.scaleFactor, txtBounds.centerX(), txtBounds.centerY());
```

The box might also be translated to antoher point. 
Any ideas? I can also post more source code, if needed.